# How to match one&many using regex in php?

Tags: php, regex

### I got an irregular codes, I tried DOM but it can't loadHTML or loadXML correctly. Then I have to use regex to match the particular content.

I want to get c&d's content in `a[b=1]`. but now i can only get content1.1.

Can anyone tell me why `(<d>(.+)</d>\s+)+` cant match all `d`? I can't find any error about this expression.

Thanks.

```
<?php
$a = "
<a b=1>
    blabla
    <c>content1:</c>
    <d>content1.1</d>
    <d>content1.2</d>

    <c>content2:</c>
    <d>content2.1</d>
</a>
<a b=2>
    blabla
    <c>content1:</c>
    <d>content1.1</d>
</a>
";

preg_match_all("|<a b=1>.+(<c>(.+):</c>\s+(<d>(.+)</d>\s+)+)+.+</a>|isU", $a, $tmp);

var_dump($tmp);exit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried DOM but it can't loadHTML

I think you should concentrate on why you can't parse the HTML with DOM. Regex is not the tool for parsing HTML, seriously!

---

As for your specific question, it's because it returns the first match:

```
<a b=1>
    blabla
    <c>content1:</c>
    <d>content1.1</d>≪≪-----here
    <d>content1.2</d>
```

Remember you're using the `U` flag, so all repetition is satisfied. And the regex engine attempts a second match from there, but it won't match your whole expression.

If you want to match all `<d>` tags nested in `<a b=1>`, you can use the [`\G` assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html), which matches at the first matching position in the subject.

**Regex**

```
~\G(?:(?!\A)|.*<a b=1>)(?:(?!</a>).)+<d>(.+)</d>~isU
```

<kbd>[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/uZ8wG9/2)</kbd>

Comment: I removed "attempt anchor", since I haven't seen that terminology before (even as a *de facto* terminology).

Comment: @nhahtdh I'm not sure where I've read it, but I think it was `\A` assertion in TCL (same behaviour as `\G` in PCRE), though I know it's not widely used. http://www.regular-expressions.info/refanchors.html refers to both as "attempt anchor". However, I'll use "`\G`assertion", just like [pcre.txt](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) refers to it.